# Nuxt 3: Open route as modal

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

This is what I am trying to achieve:

**pages/index.vue:**

```
<nuxt-link to="/subpage/a">A</nuxt-link>
<nuxt-link to="/subpage/b">B</nuxt-link>
<nuxt-link to="/subpage/c">C</nuxt-link>
```

Then when clicking one of these subpage links, I would like to have it open a modal on top of the current page, and loading the page inside a component Modal.vue.

**components/Modal.vue**

```
<div class="modal">
  This is subpage {{ id }}
</div>
```

I need to be nuxt-links, since I need to be able to deep link directly to one of the subpages.

How do I go about this? Can I use a nested NuxtPage.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can pass `params` to the subpage. When the subpage is mounted, the Modal[dot]vue will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this in your pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    <nuxt-link to="/subpage/a">A</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="/subpage/b">B</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="/subpage/c">C</nuxt-link>

    <Modal v-if="isModalOpen" @close="closeModal">
    <router-view />
    </Modal>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from '~/components/Modal.vue';

export default {
components: {
    Modal,
},
data() {
    return {
    isModalOpen: false,
    };
},
methods: {
    openModal() {
    this.isModalOpen = true;
    },
    closeModal() {
    this.isModalOpen = false;
    },
},
};
</script>
```

Comment: When will the `openModal` function be called in the current page? @Mohamed Mostafa.